# Fill labels in order

Tags: swift, xcode6

Hope everyone can help me? I hope I find the best way. I have a pickerview. This pickerview overgive value (Choosing from user) for calculate into a label. The result of the calculate will show in label1. Now my question is "How can I realize it to overgive the first result to label ausgabe, the second result to labelausgabe1 if label ausgabe is filled otherwise fill label ausgabe1 and so on....and save the results on runtime". Thanks in advance

```
import Foundation

class Balkenbewehrung : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var multiplicator : Double = 1.0

var pickerDataSource = ["Ø 6",
                        "Ø 8",
                        "Ø 10",
                        "Ø 12",
                        "Ø 14",
                        "Ø 16",
                        "Ø 20",
                        "Ø 25",
                        "Ø 26",
                        "Ø 28",
                        "Ø 30",
                        "Ø 32",
                        "Ø 36",
                        "Ø 40",
                        "Ø 50"]
@IBOutlet var menü: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var ausgabe: UILabel!

@IBAction func b(sender: AnyObject) {

   let result = multiplicator * (txt.text as NSString).doubleValue

    ausgabe.text = "\(result)"

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    menü.target = self.revealViewController()
    menü.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
    myPicker?.delegate = self
    myPicker?.dataSource = self
    myPicker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    myPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(row==0)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==1)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==2)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==3)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==4)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==5)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==6)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==7)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==8)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==9)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==10)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==11)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==12)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==13)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }
    else if(row==14)
    {
        myLabel.text = "0.478"
        multiplicator = 0.478
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Andreas, deine Frage ist sehr verwirrend, kannst du deinen Workflow etwas genauer beschreiben, am besten mit einem konkreten Beispiel - Andreas, your question is very confusing, could you describe your workflow a bit more in detail, preferable with a practical example

Comment: In og Beispiel wird der im PickerView hinterlegte Wert (multiplicator) mal UserEingabe Textfield(txt) über den Button(b) berechnet und im Label (ausgabe) das Resultat ausgegeben. Dieses Resultat möchte ich in einem Label/Textfield(Wert1) speichern. Wenn U. dann erneut eine Pickerauswahl trifft und mit  (txt) über (b) berechnet soll der neue Wert ebenfalls in einem Label/Textfield (Wert2)zwischengespeichert werden. Hier soll wenn Label (Wert1) leer ist, dann mit Wert2 befüllt werden, wenn Label(Wert1) befüllt, dann Label(Wert2) befüllen usw. Aus den Labels soll Summe gezogen werden können.

Comment: In the above example, the value stored in the Picker View ( multiplier ) is times User Input Text Field ( txt ) on the button ( b ) and output the result in the label ( output ) . This result I want to save in a Label / Text Field ( Value1 ) . When U. again meets a picker selection and the new value ( value2 ) charged ( txt ) over ( b ) should also be stored in a Label / TextField . Here is when label ( value1 ) is empty , then filled with value2 if label filled ( value 1 ) , then label ( value2 ) filling , etc. From the Labels to sum ​​can be drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, it assumes two `UILabel` `wert1` and `wert2`.

- If `wert1` is empty put the string in `wert1`
- If `wert2` is empty put the string in `wert2`
- If none of the labels is empty perform the operation.

  ```
  @IBAction func b(sender: AnyObject) {

    let result = multiplicator * (txt.text as NSString).doubleValue
    let resultString = "\(result)"

    ausgabe.text = resultString

    if wert1.text.isEmpty {
      wert1.text = resultString
    } else if wert2.text.isEmpty {
      wert2.text = resultString
    } else {
      doMultiplication()
    }
  ```

  }

you can simplify the `pickerView:didSelectRow:` method by using an array of multiplicator values and an `NSNumberFormatter` to get a localized string

```
let multiplicators  = [0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478, 0.478]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  multiplicator = multiplicators[row]
  let multiplicatorString = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: multiplicator), numberStyle: .DecimalStyle)
  myLabel.text = multiplicatorString
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I change all. But on wert1.text i have a mistake. He shows a Build Fail = value of optional type String? not unwrapped. I must insert a !. But nothing is show in wert1 in runtime....